# how to copy an array of float numbers to an array of float numbers in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, double

I've tried with strcpy(it says it requires char type of a string) and didn't work

Here is the code:

```
void AddNewTemp(void) {


int i=0,x,k=1,z=0,f=0;
float Sum=0.00;
float temperatures[8];

do{
fflush(stdin);
printf("Temperatures for how many weeks are you going to add:(1 - 1 week, 2 - 2 weeks, 3 - weeks, 4 - one month");
scanf("%d",&x);
}while(i<0 || i>4);


for(i=0;i<x;i++) {
    struct Node* temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));



    printf("Enter temperatures for week[%d]: ",k);

        for(z=0;z<7;z++) {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nDay[%d]: ",z+1);
            scanf("%lf",&temperatures[z]);
        }



    if(head==NULL) {
        head = temp;
        current = head;
    }
    else
    {
        current->next = temp;
        current = temp;
    }
        strcpy(current->temperature,temperatures);


        for(f=0;f<7;f++){
            if(temperatures[f] < temperatures[f+1]) current->tempMin = temperatures[f];
            if(temperatures[f] > temperatures[f+1]) current->tempMax = temperatures[f];
            Sum = Sum + temperatures[f];
        }

        current->tempAvg = Sum/7;
        current->next = NULL;

k++;

    printf("Information added successfully.");
```

}

}

And this is my struct:

```
struct Node {
    float temperature[8];
    float tempMin;
    float tempMax;
    float tempAvg;
    struct Node* next;
```

};

And I've tried with pointers as well, it didn't work(got an error with the incrementation).

Comment: and **read** the **documentation** of a function if you intend to use it... brainless blind assumptions are no good science.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You should properly align your code before posting it. This mess is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `memcpy` instead, `strcpy` is used to copy string arrys.